# Talend: View error in Soap response when war file is executed using Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, talend

We are running a Talend job (.war file) using apache tomcat. When we execute the job, on error, we get status = 1 in the soap response but we are not able to see error in soap response in the browser

URL we are executing looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/job_0.1/services/job?method=runJob&args1=--context_param%20CollectionRuleID=2
```

In browser, we see

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <runJobReturn xsi:type="ns1:runJobReturn">
            <ns1:item xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOf_xsd_string">
                <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ns1:item>
            </ns1:item>
        </runJobReturn>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but there is no error description. What should we do so that we can see error in Soap response.

Note: In apache tomcat console, error is getting displayed but we are not able to see that in soap response.

Comment: Can't you duplicate the tSoap response content ? If you can, then output it to a log file.

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia - We are actually not using soap component in talend job. Tomcat itself is forming this soap response and because of that we are not sure how to manipulate the soap response. Do you have any example which we can use to utilize tSoap component and get better output response?